# onReceiptReceived is never handled for DelieveryReceipts

Tags: android, smack

```
Openfire 4.0.2
smack 4.1.7
Android Studio 2.1.2
```

I am trying to use DeliveryReceipts so that I know that the message has been sent. However, `onReceiptReceived` is never called.
I have done the following:

```
DeliveryReceiptManager deliveryReceiptManager = DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(mClientConnection);  
        deliveryReceiptManager.autoAddDeliveryReceiptRequests();  
        DeliveryReceiptManager.setDefaultAutoReceiptMode(DeliveryReceiptManager.AutoReceiptMode.always);  

        deliveryReceiptManager.addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onReceiptReceived(String fromJid, String toJid, String receiptId, Stanza receipt) {  
                log.log(Level.INFO, "OnReceiptReceived fromJid: " + fromJid + " toJid: " + toJid + " receiptId: " + receiptId);  
            }  
        });
```

Sending the message:

```
ChatManager chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(mClientConnection);  
Message msg = new Message(username, Message.Type.chat);  
msg.setBody(message);  
final String msgReceipt = DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(msg);  
log.log(Level.INFO, "msgReceiptRequest: " + msgReceipt);          
Chat chat = chatManager.createChat(username, mChatMessageListener);  
chat.sendMessage(message);
```

Send from the client

```
SENT (0): <message to='97.steve@xmpp1.call-genie.com' id='6xS4w-43' type='chat'><body>hello</body><thread>32091ad3-8da9-4758-9656-c06eb72532a2</thread><request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/></message>
```

On the receiving client

```
<message to='97.steve@xmpp1.call-genie.com' id='6xS4w-43' type='chat'><body>hello</body><thread>32091ad3-8da9-4758-9656-c06eb72532a2</thread><request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/></message>
```

`onReceiptReceived` is never handled so I don't know if the receiving client received the message

I have tried to do something like this when the client receives the message which I was thinking to send back which might trigger the onReceiptReceived event

```
chat.addMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message msg) {  
        if(!msg.getBody().isEmpty()) {  
            Message ms = new Message();  
            ms.addBody("EN", "delivered");  
            ms.setTo(msg.getFrom());  
            ms.setStanzaId(msg.getStanzaId());  
            DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(ms);  
            mClientConnection.sendStanza(ms);  
        }  
        log.log(Level.INFO, "receiveChatMessages Received prompted message: " + msg.getBody());                                  
    }  
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by manually sending the receipt. When the client how received the message I have manually sent back the receipt to the sender.

```
        mChatMessageListener = new ChatMessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                log.log(Level.INFO, "Received message: " + message.getBody() + " from: " + chat.getParticipant());
                if(message != null || !message.getBody().isEmpty()) {
                    DeliveryReceiptManager deliveryReceiptManager = DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(mClientConnection);
                    if(DeliveryReceiptManager.hasDeliveryReceiptRequest(message)) {
                        log.log(Level.INFO, "hasDeliveryReceiptRequest == true");

                        Stanza received = new Message();
                        received.addExtension(new DeliveryReceipt(message.getStanzaId()));
                        received.setTo(message.getFrom());
                        try {
                            mClientConnection.sendStanza(received);
                        }
                        catch(NotConnectedException ex) {
                            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "NotConnectedException: " + ex.getMessage());
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex) {
                            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
......
```

Comment: if(DeliveryReceiptManager.hasDeliveryReceiptRequest(message)) this condition is always false even in my case on receipt received is never triggered.. any workarounds ??

Answer (score 0):

@Moulesh You might have already figured this out later.
DeliveryReceiptManager.hasDeliveryReceiptRequest(message) will be true only if you call DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(message); right after chat.sendMessage(message).